# Extracting a value from html table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract a value from a html table using `bs4`, however the structure of the table is in the form of:

```
<td class="celda400" vAlign="center" align="right" width="100" bgColor="#DFEDFF" style="color:Black">
575,42
</td>
```

The value I'm interested in is `575,42`, however it has no id or other identifier to be used by `bs4` to be extracted.

How can I call this value? Or under what id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the attributes to extract. For example, to use the

`class = "celda400"` attribute

```py
response.find('td', {'class':"celda400"}).string
```

Comment: Much better and clean, however I'm still seeing the entire data. The problem is that the only value that I need is 575,42. With your recomendation is much cleaner but still see this:  <td align="right" bgcolor="#DFEDFF" class="celda400" style="color:Black" valign="center" width="100">
                                         575,42
                                     </td>,

Comment: Calling `.string` should give you just the data inside the tag. Please accept the answer by clicking the tick if this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks! I believe that `value = soup.find('td', {'class':"celda400"}).text` worked, now I'm dealing with the loop, since I have 60 lines in which I need to extract the values. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it. I think, you can understand it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <td class="celda400" vAlign="center" align="right" width="100" bgColor="#DFEDFF" style="color:Black">
    575,42
    </td>
    <td class="celda400" vAlign="center" align="right" width="100" bgColor="#DFEDFF" style="color:Black">
    875,42
    </td>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

all_td = soup.find_all('td', {'class':"celda400"})

for td in all_td:
    value = td.text.strip()
    print(value)
```

Comment: It works, thanks, since I have at least 60 similar lines what I need now is to create a loop. Again thanks for the help!

Comment: quick question, I'm having problem extracting the values of interest using a loop, in other words I'm interested in extracting all the numerical values (just like 575,42) from 50 lines similar to the one you created in the example. Are you aware of something from bs4 that can make this task eaiser?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<td class="celda400" vAlign="center" align="right" width="100" bgColor="#DFEDFF" style="color:Black">
575,42
</td>
<td class="celda400" vAlign="center" align="right" width="100" bgColor="#DFEDFF" style="color:Black">
575,43
</td>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
texts = doc.selects('td.celda400').text
print (texts)
```

Result:

```
['575,42', '575,43']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples