# Extract a value from html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve a value from this HTML using bs4. I'm really new to data scraping and I have tried to figure out some ways to get this value but to no avail. The closest solution I saw is this one.
[Extracting a value from html table using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390480/extracting-a-value-from-html-table-using-beautifulsoup)

Here is the HTML of which I am looking at:

```
<div class="dataItem_hld clearfix">
<div class="smalltxt">ROE</div>
<div name="tixStockRoe" class="value">121.362</div>
</div>
```

I've tried this so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
url = "https://www.bursamarketplace.com/mkt/themarket/stock/SUPM"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')

val = soup.find_all('div', {'name': "tixStockRoe", 'class':"value"})
```

Before I want to try to use strip() to get the value, my `val` variable is empty.

```
In [96]: val
Out[96]: []
```

I've been searching the posts for few hours, but I did not manage to type the correct code to get the value yet.

Also, please let me know if there are any good sources to learn about extracting data. Thanks

**Update**
I have edited the code thanks to the response to the post. Now I encounter a problem. It seems like the number 121.362 did not appear in the variable. Any idea here?

```
val = soup.find_all(attrs={'name': "tixStockRoe"})
```

and the output is this:

```
Out[14]: [<div class="value" name="tixStockRoe"><div class="loader loaderSmall"><div class="loader_hld"><img alt="" src="/img/loading.gif"/></div></div></div>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in that page is loaded by JavaScript and that is the reason you aren't finding the data you are looking for - *`121.362`* using `beautifulsoup`.

> `beautifulsoup` only works on static websites.

You need to use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load the page and get data. You can read more about web-scraping using selenium [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/web-scraping-selenium-with-python/)

Here is how you scrape using `Selenium`.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") 

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=options)

url = 'https://www.bursamarketplace.com/mkt/themarket/stock/SUPM'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

d = soup.find('div', attrs= {'name': 'tixStockRoe'})
print(d.text.strip())
```

```
121.362
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the insight about Selenium, @Ram. Just a quick question, Selenium can be used for most of the URLs?

Comment: Yes. But Selenium is mostly used when the page your are trying to scrape uses a lot of JS to load the data. Otherwise, ```beautifulsoup``` will be sufficient.

Comment: Ok I learned something new today. Thanks again! By the way, did you get the error saying that 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH? I saw many posts and it seems like this chromedriver is somewhat sensitive to new update.

Comment: No, I did not. Simple hack is: *Place the ```chromedriver.exe``` in the same directory as your python script.*

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

You can't use a keyword argument to search for HTML’s `name` element.

```py
name_soup.find_all(attrs={"name": "tixStockRoe"})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the Docs! I will read through all those after this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
# I do not know lxml, in my case this parser is working
soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')

val = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'name': "tixStockRoe", 'class':"value"})
```